# Active Directory move a user to a different OU

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm working on a program that will automate the separation process for users leaving our network. One of the tasks it performs is moving the user account from the OU it is in, to a `Former Employees` OU. I've been having problems with this step even though I've not had any issues doing other processes with `DirectoryServices`. Here's my code thus far (note: I know I need to stop catching and eating all exceptions. This will be addressed and corrected before release. Any advice on which exceptions I should catch and which I should not would be appreciated too):

```
private const string AD_DOMAIN_NAME = "domain.com";
private const string AD_NEW_PASSWORD = "TestPassword123";
private const string AD_FORMER_EMPLOYEES_OU = "LDAP://OU=Former Employees,DC=domain,DC=com";

static DirectoryEntry CreateDirectoryEntry(string connectionPath, 
        string adUserName, string adPassword)
{
    DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = null;

    try
    {
        ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry(AD_DOMAIN_NAME, adUserName, adPassword);
        ldapConnection.Path = connectionPath;
        ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;                
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception Caught in createDirectoryEntry():\n\n" + ex.ToString());
    }

    return ldapConnection;
}

private void btnProcessSeparation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cboOffice.SelectedItem != null && lstUsers.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        string userOU = cboOffice.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string userName = lstUsers.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string userDn = "LDAP://OU=" + userOU + ",OU=Employees,DC=domain,DC=com";

        using (DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = CreateDirectoryEntry(userDn))
        {
            using (DirectorySearcher searcher = CreateDirectorySearcher(ldapConnection,
                SearchScope.OneLevel, "(samaccountname=" + userName + ")", "samaccountname"))
            {
                SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();

                if (result != null)
                {
                    using (DirectoryEntry userEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry())
                    {
                        if (userEntry != null)
                        {
                            using (DirectoryEntry formerEmployees = CreateDirectoryEntry(
                                AD_FORMER_EMPLOYEES_OU))
                            {
                                userEntry.MoveTo(formerEmployees); // This line throws an DirectoryServicesCOMException.
                            }

                            userEntry.CommitChanges();
                            userEntry.Close();
                            MessageBox.Show("Separation for {0} has completed successfully.", userName);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error, you did not select an OU or a user. Please try again.");
    }
}
```

The above code works just fine until the `userEntry.MoveTo(formerEmployees);` line. That line throws a `DirectoryServicesCOMException` with the additional information saying `An invalid dn syntax has been specified.` It is strange because I'm using the same format as the other `DirectoryEntry`'s that work just fine. I've added a break point and confirmed that `formerEmployees` is set to: `LDAP://OU=Former Employees,DC=domain,DC=com`. I copied everything after `LDAP://` directly from the OU's `distinguishedName` attribute in Active Directory to make sure it was correct.

Is the space in the OU name causing the problem? I got this to work once just fine and moved on to the other tasks and must have changed something that broke this. I've been looking at the code too much I think and just can't seem to see why it thinks I'm sending an invalid dn.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: "Is the space in the OU name causing the problem?" Create a new OU without a space and test it. Another thing to check is whether you have write access to the former employees' OU. Lastly, try reading from `AD_FORMER_EMPLOYEES_OU` to see if it's a DN format problem or some other problem.

Comment: @David Thanks for the advice. It turned out to be a permissions issue. I added an overloaded `CreateDirectoryEntry` method that uses the username and password (which is what I put in the code above). However, if you notice in the code above, I call the method that only takes the connection path. Doh! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @David pointed me in the right direction of making sure I had the correct permissions to the OU, I discovered the problem. I added an overloaded CreateDirectoryEntry method that uses the username and password (which is what I put in the code above). However, if you notice in the code above, I call the method that only takes the connection path.

Thanks for the help @David!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
 DirectoryEntry eLocation = Conexion.Conectar(Localitation);
 DirectoryEntry nLocation =Conexion.Conectar(NewLocalitation);
                        string newName = eLocation.Name;
                        eLocation.MoveTo(nLocation, newName);
                        nLocation.Close();
                        eLocation.Close();
```

Comment: You should not use any other language than English.

Comment: what is ***Conexion.Conectar*** ?