# Moving AD user from OU to another using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I'm writing code to move AD user from one OU to another OU. I've read many answers in stackoverflow and I finally came to the following code:

```
            string userToBeMoved = "SomeUserName"; // the username (login name) of a user who exists in AD
        string sourceLdapPath = "LDAP://OU=SourceOU,DC=MyDomainName,DC=com";
        DirectoryEntry sourceLdapConnection = new DirectoryEntry(sourceLdapPath, adUserName, adPassword);                
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(sourceLdapConnection)
        {
            SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree,
            Filter = "(&" +
                "(objectClass=user)" +
                "(samaccountname=" + userToBeMoved + ")" +
            ")"
        };

        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedname");

        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

        using (DirectoryEntry userEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry())
        {                    
            if (userEntry != null)
            {
                string targetLdapPath = "LDAP://OU=TargetOU,DC=MyDomainName,DC=com";
                using (DirectoryEntry targetLdapConnection = new DirectoryEntry(targetLdapPath, adUserName, adPassword))
                {                            
                    // this is the line at which it breaks
                    userEntry.MoveTo(targetLdapConnection);                            
                }                        
            }
        }
```

The above code gives the following error:

> invalid dn syntax has been specified

The same question is asked in the article ([Active Directory move a user to a different OU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331727/active-directory-move-a-user-to-a-different-ou)) however, the answer there is not clear and the code provided is the same code that was provided in the question (which was wrong)

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: At which statement/method is this error thrown?

Comment: At this line:
userEntry.MoveTo(targetLdapConnection);

Comment: dupplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331727/active-directory-move-a-user-to-a-different-ou

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Active Directory move a user to a different OU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331727/active-directory-move-a-user-to-a-different-ou)

Comment: Actually, I used the code provided in the mentioned article and it produced this error